# Why does my User.IsInRole("MyRole") failing with manual added roles?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC website where I have an Index that I want to limit to a specific role (call it "MyRole" for now). I initially did this:

```
[Authorize(Roles="MyRole")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

I manually added the role to the database, a simple insert into Roles with the appropriate ApplicationId and then added that new Role into the UsersInRoles table with my user. Seems pretty straight forward, but that Authorize above fails. So I tried this instead:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (!User.IsInRole("MyRole"))
        return Redirect("Error");
    return View();
}
```

The Authorize works (makes me login) but the User.IsInRole("MyRole") is returning false. I can't for the life of me figure out why. The user is in the database, the user is assigned to the application, the role is in the database for that application and the user is assigned to that role. What else do I need to do to allow for a user to be assigned to a role?

-shnar

Comment: Maybe a cache cookie issue if not done yet, you may try to clean-up your cookies and set cacheRolesInCookie to false in web.config. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms164660%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try:

```
using (RoleManager<IdentityRole> rm = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(YOUR_DATABASE_CONTEXT)))
    {
       if (!rm.RoleExists("MyRole"))
           rm.Create(new IdentityRole("MyRole"));
    }
```

instead of manually adding a role to the Roles table.